# TCP Socket.Receive() call later than arriving data: will it be lost?

Tags: c#, sockets

In all docs I found so far the "true" behaviour of the `.Receive()` method (also `.Send()`)   is never mentioned. If I didn't issue a receive prior to data arriving at the socket, will it be lost or is there an OS layer down somewhere, buffering this data? Is this the `ReceiveBufferSize` property in the `Socket` object?

Comment: It won't be lost. Lower levels of the stack will bigger it. If they get full they will quench the source

Comment: as @CaiusJard it will be buffered, same applies to the send to, unless u flush it, sends are buffered too

Comment: By "bigger" I meant "buffet", sorry (DYAC). Hah, no really Siri.. BUFFER

Comment: @CaiusJard the problem I am facing is that I receive unknown (in length) packets as TCP stream. Hard to gauge from the docs how to handle such a situation. First I need to receive "a variable handful of bytes" to discriminate which packet is in the stream, after that the rest of the packet.

Comment: But surely by the time they reach by our app they are no longer packets; you should be concerning yourself with pulling bytes out of the socket, and exactly what those bytes loop like defines the protocol. For example if you were coding an http server from scratch, you pull bytes out u til you e counter two new lines in a row, then you know you have your complete set of headers. You can parse the headers and know how to parse the body bytes. Are you really working at such a lower layer of the stack that you're picking TCP packets apart? It's very unusual...

Comment: @CaiusJard Not unusual in an industrial/embedded environment where you have to decode weird-XY-protocol from roll-our-own-standards corp. The thing is, there is no way to find the end of a packet if you don't decode it on the fly - the easiest mental model is an array which is carrying its own length in an integer which comes before the field elements. Much more complicated constructs are the norm tho (jagged arrays e.g.). I wrote a decoder-generator, so reading a packet isn't a problem - the awkward async programming models in C# and Windows are.